# Using gsub with multiple conditions to substitute a list of words in a PDF

Tags: r, text, gsub

The following code works in r:

```
pdf <- pdf_text("xyz.pdf") 
text <- c(pdf)
text_df <- tibble(line = 1:2, text = text)
words <- text_df %>%
unnest_tokens(word, text) 
x <- words
y <- gsub("apple","fruit", x) 
y
```

What I need help with is adding multiple conditions for the sub:

I would also like to substitute 
"banana", "fruit"
"squash", "vegetable"

Am I able to make a list for a large document?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a substring replacement, an option is a loop with `gsub`.  Create two vectors for the pattern and replacement (with same length), then loop over the sequence of the vector and do the replacement with `gsub` and assign it to the same object

```
pat <- c("apple", "banana", "squash")
replace <- c("fruit", "fruit", "vegetable")
for(i in seq_along(pat)) x<- gsub(pat[i], replace[i], x)
```

---

If it is a fixed match, we don't need the `gsub` as we can use a named vector to do the match and replace

```
x <- c("apple", "apple", "banana", "squash", "banana")
unname(setNames(replace, pat)[x])
#[1] "fruit"     "fruit"     "fruit"     "vegetable" "fruit"
```

Comment: Substring replacement, the first code worked great. Thank you.